# Force disable page prediction of Microsoft Edge from webpage

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with the Angular2 app I'm building. Namely I want to show a  using *ngIf with a value that changes on a click event in another element. That works fine in Chrome, IE and Firefox, but in Edge it doesn't. Except when edge's page prediction feature is turned off.

Is there a way to, either by an html tag or javascript or anything to tell Edge that it shouldn't predict this page? When I search on Google I only find lifehack style websites telling me how to turn it in my browser, but not whether a dev can force edge not to predict this website/page.

I'm asking this question because the application I'm building might be used in a company that has fully switched to windows 10, where the employees can only use Edge as their browser and might even not be able to edit the "advanced settings."

Either way, whether that is the case or not being able to disable page prediction from the website will save a lot of support questions that end in "Can you go to settings>advanced settings>page prediction and turn that off?"

Thanks a bunch,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

I googled some errors I got in the Edge dev tools console and ended up reading your question.

Error in edge console:

"PRERENDER13100: Prerender requested by FlipAhead started for url: ..."

My errors makes me think Edge's page prediction feature is based on a IE feature called "Flip Ahead". This [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj883726(v=vs.85).aspx) has this to say about Flip Ahead:
"Targets that you identify using the rel attribute of the link element take precedence over any target "suggestions" that Internet Explorer may determine."

So I'm thinking, what if you use a dummy ["link rel=next"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#sequential-link-types) tag, or perhaps a "link rel=prerender" tag, that points to nothing special. Will that make Edge stop caring about your angular tag?

This is obviously a very bad/hacky thing to do. In the rel=next case it could  mess with your SEO ranking, but at the time of writing this there's no other answers to your question, so maybe it's better than nothing in your particular case.